# c++ (XORString): "recursive type or function dependency context too complex"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to use the following XORString template/macro to encrypt string literals at compile time:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace utils {

    template <int X> struct EnsureCompileTime {
        enum : int {
            Value = X
        };
    };

    //Use Compile-Time as seed
#define compile_seed (  (__TIME__[7] - '0') * 1  + (__TIME__[6] - '0') * 10     +   \
                            (__TIME__[4] - '0') * 60   + (__TIME__[3] - '0') * 600  +   \
                            (__TIME__[1] - '0') * 3600 + (__TIME__[0] - '0') * 36000    )

    constexpr int LinearCongruentGenerator(int Rounds) {
        return 1013904223 + 1664525 * ((Rounds > 0) ? LinearCongruentGenerator(Rounds - 1) : compile_seed & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

#define Random() EnsureCompileTime<LinearCongruentGenerator(10)>::Value //10 Rounds
#define RandomNumber(Min, Max) (Min + (Random() % (Max - Min + 1)))

    template <int... Pack> struct IndexList {};

    template <typename IndexList, int Right> struct Append;
    template <int... Left, int Right> struct Append<IndexList<Left...>, Right> {
        typedef IndexList<Left..., Right> Result;
    };

    template <int N> struct ConstructIndexList {
        typedef typename Append<typename ConstructIndexList<N - 1>::Result, N - 1>::Result Result;
    };

    template <> struct ConstructIndexList<0> {
        typedef IndexList<> Result;
    };

    template <typename Char, typename IndexList> class XorStringT;
    template <typename Char, int... Index> class XorStringT<Char, IndexList<Index...> > {

    private:
        Char Value[sizeof...(Index)+1];

        static const Char XORKEY = static_cast<Char>(RandomNumber(0, 0xFFFF));

        template <typename Char>
        constexpr Char EncryptCharacterT(const Char Character, int Index) {
            return Character ^ (XORKEY + Index);
        }

    public:
        __forceinline constexpr XorStringT(const Char* const String)
            : Value{ EncryptCharacterT(String[Index], Index)... } {}

        const Char *decrypt() {
            for (int t = 0; t < sizeof...(Index); t++) {
                Value[t] = Value[t] ^ (XORKEY + t);
            }

            Value[sizeof...(Index)] = static_cast<Char>(0);

            return Value;
        }

        const Char *get() {
            return Value;
        }
    };

#define XORSTR( String ) ( utils::XorStringT<char, utils::ConstructIndexList<sizeof( String ) - 1>::Result>( String ).decrypt() )
}
```

The code is not mine, and I know very little about c++ templates or metaprogramming. The code works as intended on small strings (<250 characters), however, I need to get it working on long strings as well (thousands of characters).

When I use the `XORSTR` macro on string literals with thousands of characters, I get a "recursive type or function dependency context too complex" error during compilation.

I've tried figuring out exactly what the code does, and it seems like these lines recursively construct some kind of compile-time array (?) from the input string, and the `ConstructIndexList` line is what generates the error:

```
template <typename IndexList, int Right> struct Append;
    template <int... Left, int Right> struct Append<IndexList<Left...>, Right> {
        typedef IndexList<Left..., Right> Result;
    };

    template <int N> struct ConstructIndexList {
        typedef typename Append<typename ConstructIndexList<N - 1>::Result, N - 1>::Result Result;
    };
```

Since I have little knowledge of templates, I'm not sure how exactly to approach this problem.

One idea I had was to pass the macro substrings of the original literal and then concatenate them (in a procedural manner, not manually), however...I have no idea how to do compile-time substring/concatenation operations on literals, and maybe that's impossible.

Another idea was to simply split up my literals manually, passing the split strings to `XORSTR` individually, and then manually concatenating the results, but that creates a lot of mess in my code....considering that I need to run `XORSTR` on tens of thousands of characters, and the error pops up when >~250 characters are passed to it.

Any other ideas would be appreciated...or if someone has another compile-time string obfuscation implementation that can take string literals of any arbitrary length...that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, your `ConstructIndexList` make (rougly) the work of `std::make_integer_sequence` (available from C++14).

So I suppose you can write

```
template <typename>
struct cilH;

template <int ... Is>
struct cilH<std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>>
 { using type = IndexList<Is...>; };

template <int N>
struct ConstructIndexList
 { using Result = typename cilH<decltype(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{})>::type; };
```

avoiding you recursion bottleneck.

(but remember to `#include <utility>`).

But, I suppose, `ConstructIndexList` can be avoided at all if you use the type `std::size_t`, instead of `int`, for your indexes.

I suppose your code can be simplified as follows

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace utils
 {
   constexpr std::size_t compSeed {
          (__TIME__[7] - '0') * 1U
        + (__TIME__[6] - '0') * 10U
        + (__TIME__[4] - '0') * 60U
        + (__TIME__[3] - '0') * 600U
        + (__TIME__[1] - '0') * 3600U
        + (__TIME__[0] - '0') * 36000U };

   constexpr std::size_t linCongrGen (std::size_t rou)
    { return 1013904223U + 1664525U * ((rou > 0U)
        ? linCongrGen(rou - 1U)
        : compSeed & 0xFFFFFFFFU); }

   constexpr std::size_t randNumber (std::size_t mn, std::size_t mx)
    { return mn + (linCongrGen(10U) % (mx - mn + 1U)); }

   template <typename, typename>
   class XorStringT;

   template <typename Char, std::size_t ... Is>
   class XorStringT<Char, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
    {
      private:
         Char Value[sizeof...(Is)+1U];

         static constexpr Char XORKEY = Char(randNumber(0, 0xFFFF));

      public:
         constexpr XorStringT (Char const * const String)
            : Value{ Char(String[Is] ^ (XORKEY + Is))... }
          { }

         constexpr std::array<Char, sizeof...(Is)+1U> decrypt () const
          { return { { Char(Value[Is] ^ (XORKEY + Is)) ..., Char(0) } }; }

         Char const * get () const
          { return Value; }
    };
 }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto xorStr (T (&s)[N])
 { return utils::XorStringT<T,
      decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N - 1U>{})>( s ); }

int main()
 {
   constexpr auto xst = xorStr("secrettext");

   std::cout << xst.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << xst.decrypt().data() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to examine the code and propose a solution! I can confirm that your new version now accepts long strings...however, the compile-time encryption of the strings is no longer working, and strings encrypted with your new algorithm are still appearing unchanged in the generated binary. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @Tyson - no idea but you should prepare a full example of what you need.

Comment: In my code I have: {std::string str = XOTSTR("secrettext"); }. Prior to your modification of the algorithm "secrettext" appeared nowhere in the resulting binary, but now it does....so the intended obfuscation is no longer working. I don't quite understand the implication of everything you changed, so that's why I was wondering if you had any ideas.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. Another unrelated discussion about the XORString algorithm I found mentions that the constexpr has to be force inlined for it to work. I added __forceinline ahead of it in your code and now the strings appear to be obfuscated. So everything appears to be working as intended with that edit.

Comment: @Tyson - yes, I suppose that, if you can force it `constexpr` you should avoid the string in clear... but I'll think a little about it

Comment: @Tyson - modified the example transforming `decrypt()` in a `const` method that doesn't modify the crypted string but return an `std::array` of `char`s (so you can use the `object.decrypt().data()` value); I have also deleted the `XORSTR` macro and created the `xorStr()` `constexpr` function that return a `utils::XorStringT` object. The idea is put the object returned from `xorStr()` in a `constexpr` variable (`constexpr auto xst = xorStr("secrettext");`) so the compiler must elaborate, compile time, the secret string avoiding to save it in the compiled code. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Tyson - regarding `__forceinline`, I don't think it's a good idea: it's MSVC specific and useless for a method of a template class that is defined and declared inside the body of the class (so necessarily inline, as far I know).

Comment: Cool, thanks for all your help, and for explaining things so thoroughly!

Answer (score 1):

Compilers have limits and you're trying to nest templates to the depth of the length of your string.  A few years ago your compiler would have set your computer on fire for this, today you get a nice error message, it's unlikely to improve in the future.  (Even if the compiler actually found its way to the end of the string you'd be very unhappy with the speed of your compiles.)

You should consider encoding your literals offline - i.e., with a separate tool that runs (via your makefile or whatever build system you've got) over selected source headers producing generated headers (or cpps, whatever) - the *latter* of which you #include.  Perhaps you can repurpose an existing programmable template generator, or maybe you use an existing tool with "markers" in the code to indicate which strings to encode - awk would work well here - you could even put your strings in a separate "message" file and generate headers from that.

P.S. Some of these limits are documented in the specific compiler's documentation.  You could look there for limits on template nesting, or on the number of template variadic parameters, stuff like that.  To the best of my knowledge the standard only suggests minimums for these maximum limits, and those are *very* low.

Comment: Yea, I understand that trying to workaround/increase the maximum level of recursion isn't the right path to take....I'm moreso wondering if there's a clever workaround (ie, my substring idea) that doesn't require me to write external tools and such.

Comment: Sometimes the hammer you've got - the C++ compiler - just is _not_ the right tool for the nail.  And I'm speaking as a guy who loves C++. This is the best advice I have.

Comment: @Tyson The main trick here is to avoid using recursion so much. People used to talk heavily in terms of recursion on templates. Nowadays people have figured out that use packs and expansion tricks is usually much preferable. If you google for "compile time strings" you'll find there are ways to do which completely avoid recursion. But you will have to learn some more about C++... enough to the point where you understand the code you posted.